# PHP Ajax Query - Upload multiple files as blob

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am implementing a small exercise where a user can select multiple files and the files are uploaded through the database as BLOBS. However, I am not very familiar with the FormData plugin and is giving me some hard time. It looks like FormData is not fetching the files selected correctly.
 Error: ****Notice**:  Undefined index: files in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Excercise\file-report-attachments.php** on line 19**

I've already researched similar topics but no luck.

```html
<input class="fileInput" type="file" id="attachments" name="files[]" multiple>
```

```
var fileData = new FormData();

                $.each($("input[type='file']")[0].files, function(i, file) {
                    fileData.append('file', file);
                });



                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'file-report-attachments.php',
                    data: fileData,
                    contentType:false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },error: function (error) {                       
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
```

```php
<?php
    session_start(); 
    include("conn.php");

    $response = [];
    $response['dberror'] = false;
    $response['inputerror'] = false;
    $response['inserted'] = false;


    $upload_dir = 'uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
    $allowed_types = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'webm','mpg','mp2','mpeg','mp3','mp4','mpe','mpv','ogg','m4p','m4v','avi','wmv','mov','flv','ppm', 'pgm', 'pbm'); 

    // Define maxsize for files i.e 40MB 
    $maxsize = 40 * 1024 * 1024;  



    $file_names = $_FILES["files"]["name"];
    echo $file_names;

?>
```

I need to fetch the selected files via ajax and formdata (can be multiple) and process them through php.

Comment: You upload `file` data while you use. `$_FILES['files']` to fetch value from your backend

Comment: add one more line of code in `ajax` code `mimeType:"multipart/form-data",`

Comment: here is example https://www.dorcode.com/questions/50/auto-upload-picture

Answer (score 0):

You should use a loop to fetch multiple file data look like below

```
foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $name => $value) {
   if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$name])) {  
        $sourcePath = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$name]; 
        $targetPath = "images/".$_FILES['files## Heading ##']['name'][$name];
        if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
        }
   }
}
```

Thanks